# how can i declare variable in shell and use with condition instruction

Tags: bash, shell

I have a first script for exemple :

```
test1.sh
$1='world'
var1="hello world"
echo $var1
```

So, i want a script shell, which execute test1.sh according to condition :

for exemple :

```
if  [ $1= world ]; 
  #execute test1.sh
```

i don't know how to rely the two shells, if you have any suggestions i ll be thankfull !

Comment: Please find an answer to your question at the above link with a few more background info, too. Also `$1` refers to the first argument after your script when you run it, you cannot define it as you do. `bash script.sh world`  --> `echo $1` in the script will return `world`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your if condition is ill-formated. You likely look for something like

```
#!/bin/bash
var1="hello world"
if [[ "$var1" == "$1" ]]; then echo $1 found; else echo $1 not found; fi
```

It will give output like

```
$ ./test1.sh "world world"
world world not found
$ ./test1.sh "hello world"
hello world found
```

You can call another bash script simply by its name like any normal programme or command